# how to drag a file and get path of it

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

How to implement a Panel in Winform , when a user drags a file on it (a simple .txt file) , it should accept it and stores its path into some variable called filepathname etc. which can be used earlier. I could find examples on how to implement drag and drop but not on how to get the path and store it for use later in the program.
Using : Visual Studio 2008 - Vb.net

Thanks!

Comment: I upvote dosn't meant this is good, but I'm disagree someone want to downvote this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this in [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289508%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
The code below is the modificated ones

```
Private Sub Panel1_DragEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As _
System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles Panel1.DragEnter
    If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) Then
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Panel1_DragDrop(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As _
System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles Panel1.DragDrop
    If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) Then
        Dim MyFiles() As String
        Dim i As Integer

        ' Assign the files to an array.
        MyFiles = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)
        'If there are more than one file, set first only
        'If you want another restrictment, please edit this.
        filepathname = MyFiles(0)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: But just change this according to your need : "Handles ListBox1.DragDrop "

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal Opps, sorry. I am C# Programmer and don't notice the Handles ListBox1.DragDrop because in C# we don't use that.